Misunderstandings in restaurants
I've travelled a lot to many different countries in the world, and usually I can manage to get a table for two in any restaurant, even in places where I don't speak the local language. There's just a few places where I've been misunderstood, such as:

In a traditional Italian eatery, they gave me a table for five instead.
In a Lebanese restaurant and an Iraqi kebab house, they gave me a table for seven.
In a British pub, they punched me and threw me out!

What am I doing, and why is it misunderstood in those places?

I presume you keep

 Sticking up two fingers like so?
 

In a traditional Italian eatery, they gave me a table for five instead.

 Two fingers look like V which is 5 in Roman numerals…

In a Lebanese restaurant and an Iraqi kebab house, they gave me a table for seven.

 In Arabic numerals V is 7

In a British pub, they punched me and threw me out!

 Sticking up two fingers is an extremely offensive gesture in the UK!


Thank goodness he wasn't after a table for one...

Yep, that was fast! @Stiv it all depends which one ;-)

@Randal'Thor you have to be fast here lol.

Not to let reality get in the way of a good puzzle, but sticking up two fingers isn’t  extremely offensive in the UK, at least anymore.  I would say that it is outdated possibly unknown to younger generations, and I think anyone seeing it would either be confused or assume you were indicating two people. However, depending on the pub, asking for a table could be a very strange thing to do - like asking for a table at McDonalds!

@NeilTarrant I'm a younger generation from the UK myself, but perhaps I should take this as just more evidence for me being, as I often claim, a grumpy old man in the body of a young one :-)

As a middle-aged Brit, I've seen the offensiveness of the rot13(gjb-svatre fnyhgr) decrease over my lifetime, roughly parallel to the offensiveness of the equivalent words.  And the Americans' middle-finger salute seems to have risen to take its place somewhat.

Just for future visitors, the spoiler has  quite an interesting history (wikipedia will tell you) /cc @chux-ReinstateMonica
